# Encrypt Blobstorage

Tags: encryption, plone, zope

A customer's security policy requires to encrypt the data stored in a plone site on application level.
So it's okay, that a plone admin can access all information stored in the cms, but the sysadmin should not be able to copy files or browse database dumps for useful information.
(so using encfs is not an option because the sysadmin can do exactly that)

To enctrypt the database, [cipher.encryptingstorage](https://github.com/zopefoundation/cipher.encryptingstorage) should be sufficient.

Is there a way to encrypt files in zope's blobstorage in a similar way?

Comment: @RyanVincent i completely understand your point. (i also know that i - as an admin - can create an emergency zope user and access the portal with manager privileges)
however, i also understand the customers wish for that. and there is a difference in "just copying files over" or "investing some energy first"

Comment: Thanks for your viewpoint. It makes sense.

Comment: I am under the impression that cipher.encyrptingstorage encrypts both pickles and individual BLOBs.  That much seems apparent by reading the source.  Though, encrypting BLOBs in transit to underlying storage does have the security drawback of not being able to be scanned for viruses out-of-band (e.g. clamav).

Comment: @sdupton - blob encryption was not implemented yet. we started to implement this in a new pull request: https://github.com/zopefoundation/cipher.encryptingstorage/pull/1

Answer (score 3):

we finally made cipher.encryptingstorage support blobs, too.

@pcdummy described the setup in [a blogpost on our website](http://webmeisterei.com/news/encrypt-your-plone-database)